# How does Jackrabbit WebDAV generate eTag header?

Tags: java, http, webdav, jackrabbit

I have a Jackrabbit WebDAV server running in Tomcat and I want to know how **ETag** header value is generated. What class is producing it?

How it can be generated using Java based on initial file and it path in Jackrabbit repository?

The intended flow:

1. Initial file upload to the server
2. If the client is uploading a new file: calculate ETag and compare it with corresponding ETag of file on the server.
3. If values the same - do not upload the file, send response to the client. If values deffer - replace the file on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* the server will use the jcr:etag property (https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.7.12.1%20mix:etag), otherwise will try to generate something based on timestamp and file length.

Comment: I followed the link but it's for JCR. My purpose is to generate such ETag the same way as Jackrabbit does. Any ideas?

Comment: Jackrabbit is the reference implementation of the JCR spec. So setting the jcr:etag property should do it.

Comment: FWIW, I don't fully get why you want to generate the ETag in the same way? Maybe youl could elaborate in your question?

Comment: I supposed to use ETag as a fingerprint for files on the jackrabbit WebDAV server. The Idea not to save uploading file but to calculate ETag for it and check if the file on the server has the same.

Comment: Aha. That won't work due to the fact the ETags are not content-based in Jackrabbit (also note that conditions on ETags are not fully supported in Jackrabbit WebDAV (but I'm on it).

Answer (score 0):

Later inside Jackrabbit source codes I found this:

```
if (length > IOUtil.UNDEFINED_LENGTH && modTime > IOUtil.UNDEFINED_TIME) {
    String etag = "\"" + length + "-" + modTime + "\"";
    context.setETag(etag);
}
```

where: `modTime = Callendar#getTimeInMillis();`

So etag is produced on the next pattern: **size** in bytes - **modification date** converted to Long.